# LINQ enumeration list doesn't show up the error when accessed it for second time while debugging

Tags: c#, linq

I'm making a database call with linq and it is returning some results to me. Following is the code for the same:

```
var resultSet = DataContext.GetList(id);

foreach(var result in resultSet)
{
    // do something here with result
}
```

After this, I try to access again same resultSet as below:

```
foreach(var result in resultSet)
{
    // do something here with result
}
```

When I'm in debug mode it doesn't throw any error, instead it simply exits debug mode and execution is completed and focus comes back to page.

I want to know why it is not throwing any error in debug mode that I'm using the enumeration for the second time? Am I missing anything? All other errors are throwing exceptions even in the debug mode.

**Update:** I intentionally didn't do that second calling. It was done by mistake, but it took sometime for me to find that error, if it would have thrown an error, then I would have easily fixed it. This is reason I posted this question here.

Note: I'm doing this throw a ajax call.

Comment: Since you used var, we have no way of knowing the type of resultSet and no way of knowing whether it is illegal to enumerate it more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you go to `Debug (Menu)> Exceptions` and check the checkbox under `Thrown` for `Common Language Runtime Errors`. Now Visual Studio debugger should break when the error occurs and you should be able to see what's happening.